# Как замедлить видео на javascript?

Tags: javascript, видео

Привет, можно ли замедлить видео на javascript? Если да, то как? 
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4):

Вот код:

```
document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 3.0;
```

Значение `3.0` означает что видео ускорено в 3 раза. По дефолту видео воспроизводиться с нормальной скоростью, то есть `1.0`.
Чтобы замедлить видео на половину `0.5`

Answer (score 1):

Имеется фреймворк, в функционале которого в том числе имеется управление скоростью воспроизведения.
[Video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js)